# should I use fseek SEEK_END

Tags: c, fseek

My question is simple:

Should I use fseek with SEEK_END to get to the end of a file and then get the length of it ?
Because in the man it is said:

> - Library implementations are allowed to not meaningfully support SEEK_END (therefore, code using it has no real standard portability).

Right now I am using stat (from C) which is better ?

Comment: You mention `stat` and `man`, so is it safe to assume you are using Linux, or some other Unix? Do you care about other platforms?

Comment: This question is good, but the way you phrased it makes it heavily opinion based and leads to discussions, which is not desirable.

Comment: See https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/FIO19-C.+Do+not+use+fseek%28%29+and+ftell%28%29+to+compute+the+size+of+a+regular+file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `ftell` function returns a long, which means that on an ILP32 system you can't correctly get the size of a file larger than 2GB. You should use the `stat` function or similar to get the size of a file; check the manual for the operating system you're targeting in case you have use a different function name (stat64) or define a preprocessor macro to get the desired behavior for large files.

Answer (score 1):

Since C++ inherits `fseek` and `SEEK_END` from C, I'm quoting the C standard here:

> #### C11(ISO/IEC 9899:201x) §7.21.9.2 *The fseek function*  section 3
>
> A binary stream need not meaningfully support `fseek` calls with a whence value of `SEEK_END`.